# It´s possible use dual string in one

Tags: php

I need give two names for one variable as this

```
$height="little";
$terms_$height_global
```

I supose the normal it´s use :

```
$terms_height_global
```

But i need give 2 names to this variable, but i don´t know if it´s possible do this or exists some way for works as this

This it´s my question, if it´s possible something more or less as the first example for me it´s right

Thank´s other time

Comment: Are you trying to create a new variable, or just trying to string the values together?

Comment: `$terms_$height_global = &$height;`?

Comment: ${'terms_'.$height.'_global'} is like using $terms_little_global ... is that what you're looking for?

Comment: New variable , yes right happend the string need use different name and i want create new variable with different name in each case and take value of name variable from string